# Is there any way to adjust column widths when a particular row using multicolumn is too long in latex?

Tags: tables, adjustbox

I am using latex for my academic writing and wonder if there is any way to show a table in the latex document below beautifully.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4]{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{threeparttable}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}} \hline\hline 
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         \\
\hline \\ \multicolumn{5}{l}{Panel A: Outcome variable name is VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY  LONG  }\\ \hline
Treatment &    0.121        &     0.142   &      0.201    &    0.198   \\
 &    (0.151)        &    (0.242)   &      (0.301)    &   (0.298)   \\

\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

When I compiled this file, I obtained this.

[image]
I want to adjust the widths of columns (1) -- (4) to have equal widths automatically. Is there any way to do it? I want to keep `adjustbox` because it is very handy for my workflow (produce tables from `R` or `stata` and import them in my latex file).

I am using MacTeX-2022 and pdflatex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Whatever else you do, you should *not* employ the `adjustbox` machinery to shoe-horn a inadequately designed table into the available space.

Comment: The option to use A4 paper is `a4paper`, not `a4`.

Comment: Thank you two so much for the comments and answers. Both are quite helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allow line breaking to occur in the cell that contains the long string.

If you choose to implement the following solution, you will also need to specify a desired or *target* width of the whole table. In the following table, the target width is set to `0.7\textwidth`. Depending on just how long the long string is, you may need to either increase or decrease this width suitably.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' environment and 'X' column type
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedright}p{\targetwidth}}
\newlength\targetwidth
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\targetwidth{0.7\textwidth} % choose a suitable width
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\targetwidth}{@{} l CCCC @{}} 
\toprule
& (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}P@{}}{Panel A: Outcome variable name is a VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY LONG STRING}\\ 
\midrule
Treatment &  0.121   &   0.142   &   0.201   &  0.198   \\
          & (0.151)  &  (0.242)  &  (0.301)  & (0.298)  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `adjustbox` for making tables as wide as the text width, because this can lead to nonuniform font size. You can use `tabularx` instead.

I show two realizations; in the second I assume you have several parts called “Panel X”, so we can set up hanging indentation.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\panel}[3]{%
  % #1 = number of columns to span
  % #2 = name of the panel
  % #3 = text
  \multicolumn{#1}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{%
    \settowidth{\leftskip}{Panel M: }%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[\leftskip][l]{Panel #2:}}%
    #3%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  @{}
  l
  *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
  @{}
}
\toprule
& (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{Panel A: Outcome variable name is 
  VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY  LONG} \\
\midrule
Treatment &  0.121  &  0.142  &  0.201  &  0.198  \\
          & (0.151) & (0.242) & (0.301) & (0.298) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}


\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  @{}
  l
  *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
  @{}
}
\toprule
& (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
\midrule
\panel{5}{A}{Outcome variable name is 
  VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY  LONG} \\
\midrule
Treatment &  0.121  &  0.142  &  0.201  &  0.198  \\
          & (0.151) & (0.242) & (0.301) & (0.298) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `p{...}` to create a fixed column. Any text that exceeds the length of such column will be wrapped on multiple lines. It can also be used with `\multicolumn` with the same effect.

In the solution below, I made use of `threeparttable` since you have it in preamble. I also added `makecell`. I keep basic spacing between corresponding numbers with and without parentheses even if a large stretching is used, which might be a slight advantage.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    %%% Settings for makecells
    \renewcommand\cellalign{tc}
    \renewcommand\cellset{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1}}
    \renewcommand\cellgape{\gape[b]}
    %%% Settings for vertical spacing 
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.25}
    %     correction for array stretch
    \setlength\extrarowheight{-3pt}
    %%% TABLE
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{This is the caption}
        \begin{tabular}{
                p{\dimexpr\linewidth-10\tabcolsep-8.8cm}
                *4{C{2.2cm}}
            }
            \toprule
            & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
            \midrule
            \multicolumn{5}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}{%
                Panel A: Outcome variable name is VERY VERY VERY
                VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY LONG} \\
            \hline
            Treatment
            & \makecell{0.121\\(0.151)}
            & \makecell{0.142\\(0.242)}
            & \makecell{0.201\\(0.301)}
            & \makecell{0.198\\(0.298)} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \strut\footnotesize
        Comments and annotations under the table
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```